# How to Solve $3^{x+2} + 2^{x+2} + 2^x = 2^{x+5} + 3^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I was wondering how to solve this equation for x

$3^{x+2} + 2^{x+2} + 2^x = 2^{x+5} + 3^x$

This equation was found on the CEMC eWorkshop for Euclid, but no solution was included.

Thank you,
Eddie

Comment: What have you tried? My first instinct is to divide by $2^x$ and then express it as an equation for $(3/2)^x$ and then take the logarithm.

Answer (score 5):

$$3^{x+2} + 2^{x+2} + 2^x = 2^{x+5} + 3^x$$

$$9\cdot 3^x +4\cdot 2^x+2^x=32\cdot 2^x+3^x$$

$$8\cdot 3^x=27\cdot 2^x$$
$$\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x=\frac{27}8=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^3$$

Hence $x=3$.

Comment: Please do not answer bare Problem statement questions, @Sebastiano.  [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C133.5163)

Comment: @amWhy Ok. No problem.